# Laravel migration throws foreign key exception

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I'm trying to write a laravel database migration with foreign relation. during database migration throwing query exception error.

I tired to migrate tables using laravel rules but during migration it showing the unexpected error.

**Users Table**

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name', 150);
        $table->string('email', 150)->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone', 150);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Roles Table**

```
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('role_name',255);
        $table->longText('role_description',255);
        $table->integer('sort_order');
        $table->enum('status',['A','I','D'])->comment('A-active','I-inactive,D-delete'); 
        $table->enum('is_deleted',['Y','N'])->comment('Y-yes,N-no');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->bigInteger('created_by');
        $table->bigInteger('updated_by')->default(0);
        $table->bigInteger('deleted_by')->default(0);
        $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
    });
```

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `jt_users`
>   add constraint `users_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`)
>   references `jt_roles` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: It seems you missed to define the column definition for the `role_id` in users migration. Also the migration oder should matter... you must ensure the roles migration should run first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add a foreign key to a table which doesn't exist. In your case, you are trying to create a `role_id` before the `roles` table is created.

Within your `roles` table migration, you will need to update the `users` table once the `roles` table has been created:

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('role_name',255);
    $table->longText('role_description',255);
    $table->integer('sort_order');
    $table->enum('status',['A','I','D'])->comment('A-active','I-inactive,D-delete'); 
    $table->enum('is_deleted',['Y','N'])->comment('Y-yes,N-no');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->bigInteger('created_by');
    $table->bigInteger('updated_by')->default(0);
    $table->bigInteger('deleted_by')->default(0);
    $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
});

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Note:** Use `Schema::table()` instead of `Schema::create()` when making changes to a table.

On the `down()` method of the `roles` migration, you need to drop the foreign key and field:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['role_id']);
    $table->dropColumn('role_id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

at first, the table that has "primary key" (users) must be migrated